# React-i18next suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I m using React-i18next just like the example

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <MyComponent />
   </Suspense>
   );
}
```

But Suspense is breaking one of my other components, namely react-masonry-layout. Is it possible to not using Suspense?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify, how does it break your current code

Comment: in face i m not so sure whether Suspense is the culprit. But I believe so. So I would like to know how to use react-i18next without suspense. It seems Suspense is a must for i18next.

Comment: Suspense is never a must, its up to you if you want to use it. Also I don't see where exactly are you using react-i18nnext

Answer (score 18):

react-i18nnext uses Suspense by default. If you don't want to use it, you have to specify that in your configuration. If you have a i18n config file, you can set the useSuspense flag to false in the react section of the init object.

```
//Example config
i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
   fallbackLng: "en",
   debug: true,
   resources: {

   },
   interpolation: {
     escapeValue: false,
   },
  react: {
     wait: true,
     useSuspense: false,
  },
})
```

Or you can just set the flag in your component.

```
<MyComponent useSuspense={false} />
```

Just be aware that choosing not to use Suspense has its implications. You have to write checks to handle the 'not ready' state ie: have a loading component render when state is not ready and your component render when the state is ready.Not doing so will result in rendering your translations before they loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try that. I have a masonry component which needs to calculate screen width and height onload. I suspect that suspense interferes with this masonry component. So I wanna try.

Comment: Tanks for the reply, got the same problem with the suspense interrupting my `@material-ui` animations

Comment: Suspense is experimental - should we be using it in a production system ? I'm kinda surprised this is the official recommendation from react-i18next ?

Answer (score 0):

##### Date: 02/09/2021

Versions

```
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-i18next": "^8.5.1",
```

In NextJs with SSR Suspense is not supported yet. So if you need to remove that you need to disable it on `next-i18next.config.js`.

##### Issue

```js
Error: ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense.
```

##### Fix `next-i18next.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
  },
  localePath: path.resolve('./assets/locales'),
  react: {
    useSuspense: false,
  },
};
```